# Find the values of p for which there is no turning points in the curve

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, algebraic-curves

The question:

[image]

So, I have done almost everything. I am in the last part of the question. This is how I did it:

I differentiated the curve $y = x^3 + px^2 + px$ and got:

$dy/dx = 3x^2 + 2px + p$

I am not sure how to proceed from here. I would like to know how I would solve from here. Any help would be very highly appreciated. Final answer:

$0 < p < 3$

Comment: I dont know why but the image is not appearing.

Comment: Click on the link for questuon

Comment: Nevermind works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No stationary points means $$3x^2+2px+p\neq 0$$

Use the discriminant of this quadratic equation $D=(2p)^2-4\cdot 3\cdot p$. In order for a quadratic equation to have no real roots the discriminant has to be negative. Hence, $4p^2-12p<0$ or $4p(p-3)<0$.

Can you complete it from here?

**EDIT:**
A product of two real numbers can only be negative if only one of them is negative. As $p>0$ from the beginning you can conclude $p-3<0$ or $p<3$. Combined with $p>0$ we get the result $0<p<3$.

Comment: Oh I did that and thought it was wrong. How do I show it as a range?

Comment: I know the answer is 0 < p < 3 but how do you get that from $4p(p - 3) < 0$

Comment: @HassanAlthaf: I added the explanation.

Comment: How did you get p > 0?

Comment: @HassanAlthaf The exercise states p is positive. Hence, p>0.

Answer (score 0):

**Basic approach.** You now have for the derivative a quadratic expression of the form $ax^2+bx+c$.  The original curve has no stationary points if and only if the derivative has no zeros; that is, when $ax^2+bx+c = 0$ has no solutions.  Using the quadratic formula

$$
x = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}
$$

as a guide, identify the values of $p$ for which that derivative has no zeros.  (Hint: When is the quadratic formula undefined in the reals?)